# The movie has started/started a few minutes ago

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Can somebody tell me which one is grammatically correct:

> The movie has started a few minutes ago

or

> The movie started a few minutes ago

?

Comment: "Has started" reports its status -- it either has or it hasn't.  You can't combine that with when it happened.  To describe when it happened, use just "started", as in "started a few minutes ago".

Answer (score 1):

1st sentence "The movie has started a few minutes ago" is partially correct. To make it completely correct, you use "The movie has started". This means the movie has already started, doesn't matter how much time has passed. If you do want to tell how much time has passed then your 2nd sentence is correct and you can add some more to it like, "The movie started a few minutes ago, although you did not miss much"

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct.  You cannot use *has verb+ed* with ago.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little more? Provide a little explanation as to why the present perfect cannot be used with *ago*?

Answer (score 0):

Present perfect, 'has started' cannot be used with the sense of time mentioned. If you're mentioning the time then you need to use past tense. It's one of the rules in grammar.
Either say "The movie has started" or "The movie started 10 mins ago" like this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it was already said, one can't use have(has) with ago. Well, the original rule is you use the Present perfect when something happens in the past, but it has connection with the present moment. Also you just can't use PP if you stated directly, that something happened in the past. 
Your example:
The movie started a few minutes ago. So you say, that it happened, and maybe you can even see the result of it (You're watching a movie) but it happened IN THE PAST (Few minutes ago). With no other options it's only past simple - The movie started a few minutes ago. Or alternatively you can use PP but you have to leave out mentioning time - The movie has started.